# Windows ipconfig no longer displays any information

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection

Last night my XP machine could connect to the internet. Today it cannot. I've rebooted both PC and DSL Modem. When I type

```
C:\IPCONFIG  

Windows IP Configuration
```

Response is that one line and nothing else. I'm using wireless laptop connection on same modem to post this question. Where should I begin to troubleshoot my connection?

Comment: Safe Mode with Networking, Device Manager, System Restore - you pick. :)

Comment: If I choose the Device Manager route, what do I need to review?

Comment: @zundarz You would use Device Manager to check if Windows is recognizing your wireless card/adapter properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely scenario is the network card has failed.  It might be a driver issue, in which case use device manager to identify the network card, go to the vendor site and download and install new drivers.

If the network card is not present in Device Manager, or the above changes nothing, then consider purchasing a new network card (it doesn't matter if the current one is integrated or separate).

Also, make sure you do a complete shutdown to power off (at the wall is best).  A reboot does not drop power to the network card, and so if it has just gotten stuck, a reboot might not fix it where a power cycle might.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has a switch to disable wireless, it might be in the disabled position.